# How do I draw a dotted line from the paint method on a JComponent?

Tags: java, paint

I have to draw a dotted or dashed line In a JComponent. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Get a hold of a `Graphics2D`, and use its `setStroke()` method to set a suitable stroke. It should be enough with a `BasicStroke` to get a dotted line, nothing fancy.